# Swift how to write plist file and change the value?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, swift

```
let plistPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("userConfig", ofType: "plist")
let dict = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: plistPath)
let data: (AnyObject!) = dict.objectForKey("baiduUrl")
var myDictionary: String = "http://www.baidu.com"
myDictionary.setObject(plistPath, forKey: "baiduUrl")
myDictionary.writeToFile(plistPath, atomically: false)
println(myDictionary)
```

> Error :  'String' does not have a member named 'setObject'

[image]

change coding.I can not change plist
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myDictionary: String = "http://www.baidu.com" // You say you have an String called myDictionary, not a dictionary
myDictionary.setObject(plistPath, forKey: "baiduUrl") // myDictionary is a String, so you can't set any object to it.
```

What you need to do is (untested, relevant part)

```
let myString:String = "http://www.baidu.com"
var myMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
myDictionary.setObject(myString, forKey:"baiduUrl")
```

Or if your dictionary will be inmutable you can create it as NSDictionary assigning directly the myString to your key.

Answer (score 1):

You declared myDictionary as a String (and initialized it with a String literal). I'm pretty sure you meant to declare it as a Dictionary, given the name. Strings and Dictionaries are not the same thing.

Comment: declared myDictionary.Still can not write to Plist.

Comment: Please update the question with the new error as well as the new code.

Comment: change coding.I can not change plist